# Show that a summation of products of sin is zero

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Let $N_x,N_y>1$. Let $1\le l,l'\le N_x$ and $1\le k,k'\le N_y$. If $l\ne l'$ or $k\ne k'$, prove

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N_x}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N_y}\sin\left(l\cdot \frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)\sin\left(l'\cdot \frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)
\sin\left(k\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)\sin\left(k'\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)=0.$$

I've been working on this for hours and still can't figure it out. I'm sure there must be an identity that makes this clear. If I break this down into cases I have $l=l'$ and $k\ne k'$, $l\ne l'$ and $k= k'$, $l\ne l'$ and $k\ne k'$ to consider. Do to the symmetry of the summation I assume that once I show the first case I will clearly see the others.

So assume $l=l'$ and $k\ne k'$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\sin\left(l\cdot \frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)\sin\left(l'\cdot \frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)
\sin\left(k\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)\sin\left(k'\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)\\[1em]
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos\left([l-l']\frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)-\cos\left([l+l']\frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)\right]
\sin\left(k\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)\sin\left(k'\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)\\[1em]
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\cos\left(2l\frac{n\pi}{N_x+1}\right)\right]
\sin\left(k\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)\sin\left(k'\cdot \frac{m\pi}{N_y+1}\right)
\end{align*}

Under the assumption I am moving in the right direction, I don't see where to go now. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't your double sum just the product between a sum whose terms depend on $n$ and a sum whose terms depend on $m$? Both these sums can be computed in a explicit way.

Comment: So you're saying to factor out the terms with $n$, then show that the sum from $m=1$ up to $m=N_y$ is zero, thus the entire sum is zero? If so, I'm still unsure how that inner sum becomes zero

Comment: $2\sin(x)\sin(y)=\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)$, $\cos\theta=\text{Re}(e^{i\theta})$ and the problem boils down to showing that the real part of a geometric sum equals zero, pretty simple.

Comment: Just like the spelling of mentors ;)